# How to capture the result of a command sent using Expect

Tags: perl, expect.pm

I have to capture output of the send command when using Perl [`Expect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) module.

I know that in shell or Tcl I can use `puts $expect_out(buffer);` to capture the previously run command.

How can I do the same thing in Perl?

I am sending below command on remote machine:

```
$expect->send("stats\n");
```

I need to capture the `stats` output in some variable.

Comment: Did you check the Expect module documentation: http://search.cpan.org/~szabgab/Expect-1.32/lib/Expect.pm#I_just_want_to_read_the_output_of_a_process_without_expect%28%29ing_anything._How_can_I_do_this?

Comment: Also, looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908683/get-the-output-of-a-command-executed-via-self-send-on-a-remote-host-in-perl?rq=1

Comment: Yes, checked but no help..!!

Comment: This is not duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908683/get-the-output-of-a-command-executed-via-self-send-on-a-remote-host-in-perl?rq=1, this is different question.

Comment: Don't you `expect` after `send` to receive the answer?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to know how the last line of your CLI looks like after the output of your requested data. The `Expect` cann search for a certain Pattern within your defined timeout. If it found sth. you can capture everything since your `$expect->send($command)` with the `$exp-before()`-command. Or if you wish to capture everything after your command just use `$expect->after()` without checking for a special symbol.

Let me give you an example:

```
$expect->send("$command\n");
#mask the pipe-symbol for later use. Expect expects a valid regex
$command =~ s/\|/\\\|/;
#if a huge amount of data is requested you have to avoid the timeout
$expect->restart_timeout_upon_receive(1);
if(!$expect->expect($timeout, [$command])){ #timeout
   die: "Timeout at $command";
}else{
   #command found, no timeout
   $expect->after();
   $expect->restart_timeout_upon_receive(1);
   if(!expect->expect($timeout,["#"])){
     die "Timeout at $command";
   } else{
      $data = $expect->before(); #fetch everything before the last expect() call
   }
}
   return $data;
```

So you have to fire your command, then expect your command been fired. After this you can fetch everything till your command prompt, in my case it's indicated by the `#`. The rows between your command and the last `$expect->expect($timeout,["#"]` will be stored in $data as a single string. After that you can process this String.

I hope I could help you a bit further. ;)